# Qt and SSL : failed to encrypt connection in Qt5 but not in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

I'm trying to set a secure connection between a client and a server using Qt5 and Ssl. I've downloaded a Qt4 code (available here: https://github.com/dgraves/QSslChat), and it works fine. But I tried to adapt it to Qt5 and it fails to encrypt the connection. Two problems appear:

```
QSslSocket *socket = dynamic_cast<QSslSocket *>(server.nextPendingConnection());
assert(socket);
```

The assert here fails (`qDebug() << socket` prints `QObject(0x0)`), even when I replace the dynamic_cast with a qobject_cast. But when I replace it with a static_cast or a C style cast, it works, but the returned item is a QTcp Socket (`qDebug() << socket` prints `QTcpSocket(0x26ebe30)` for example)

So I tried to use `setSocketDescriptor` instead of a cast

```
 QSslSocket *socket = new QSslSocket;
 socket->setSocketDescriptor(server.nextPendingConnection()->socketDescriptor());
```

But then, the Client fails to do the `connectToHostEncrypted` (infinite loop). I put a `waitForEncrypted()`, but it timeout.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Qt 5.2.1 and OpenSSL 1.1.0c (g++ 4.8.4)

Comment: When you do dynamic_cast (generic in C++) or qobject_cast (better for QObject* base) cast and getting NULL pointer for some type that means the actual type is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Didn't know that. But then, why does it works in Qt4 and not in Qt5 ?

Comment: server.nextPendingConnection might be returning different object?

Comment: @AlexanderVX From the doc, nextPendingConnection returns a QTcp Socket * in Qt 4.8 and Qt5

Comment: But you cast it to QSslSocket, don't you? That will work if one inherited from the other.

Comment: Also, consider using a completely separate SSL/TLS proxy like nginx. That will allow you to not to bother about SSL in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply. I just updated from Qt5.2 to Qt5.7 and...it worked